# How can I search for a C++ symbol in xcode 3?

Tags: c++, xcode, symbols, xcode3.2

I'm a Visual Studio user, trying to start working with xcode. 
In visual studio to find a symbol, you can use the VisualAssist's "Find Symbol" (Shift+Alt+S).

Is there a way achieve a similar result in xcode?

Comment: Xcode 3? Really? Why are you using such an old tool? Do yourself a favor and use current tools.

Comment: not something I can choose :)
but we will go to latest version soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the left in your **file explorer** tab you have some icons above. Press the **loopglass** icon and you'll get a window where you can choose how to find/replace, where and how.

[image: Xcode lol]

Comment: thanks you, that helps. still not finding a symbol's definition as visual assist does. but it's something

Comment: @user2956500 No problem, it is a complete different IDE but you'll find other options that you not may find in VS.

Comment: in that matter, do you happen to have a good link that will describe these benefits?